# pass window width to iosSlider when hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a site that makes use of the iosSlider plugin. I have a few sliders inside of a jquery accordion so some of them start out "display:none" when the page first loads. As a result the sliders inside the accordions are not getting the proper screen width. When you open one of the hidden accordions the slider inside is tiny.

I was curious if there was a better method to solving this issue then the one I am currently using. Right now I am simply destroying the slider and recalling it but this looks ugly and I'm sure there is probably a better approach to solving this.

Any input would be great, thanks

Current code:

```
        $(".acheader").click(function(e) {
            //e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            acords.slideUp();
            $(".menuarrow").attr('src','/themes/images/arrow_down.png');

            var image = $(this).find(".menuarrow");

            if(image.attr('src') === "/themes/images/arrow_down.png"){
                image.attr('src','/themes/images/arrow_up.png');
            }

            if ($(this).next().is(":hidden")) {
                $(this).siblings(".accontent").slideToggle(100);
                $('.iosSlider2').iosSlider('destroy');
                $('.iosSlider2').iosSlider({
                    snapToChildren: true,
                    desktopClickDrag: true,
                    keyboardControls: true,
                    navNextSelector: $('.next'),
                    navPrevSelector: $('.prev'),
                    onSlideChange: slideChange2
                });
            }
            else image.attr('src','/themes/images/arrow_down.png');
        });
```

EDIT: this is for a mobile site so there are no static widths I can refer to. The sliders parents inherit their widths from their parents.. etc.

Comment: you should just set the correct width to those items. if you know something has the right width then use that and set it to all the accordion items you need. Or maybe instead of display: none you can set it to position absolute (when hidden) and top: -99999px. This way it should have the correct width, and first thing in your click handler you can remove this absolute position class with jquery

Comment: I forgot the mention that this is for a mobile site so there are no hard widths only percents. The containing div has no width defined because it inherits it's width from it's parent and so forth. The only element with any width is the global container which has a min-width and a max-width.

Comment: even so, you can still do .width() and it will return a pixel value. If you have an accordion open at the start then you can get that width after window load and apply that width to the rest of the accordions. this width should be reapplied when resizing. It's similar to a responsive design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a look at the iosSlider docs, under public methods, it looks like there is an update command which should resize it. Use `$('.iosSlider2').iosSlider('update');` instead of destroying. Does that help?